# Asp.net Web Api stop using ARRAffinity cookie

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

My API uses bearer token for authentication and the controller use Authorize attribute.

Whenever I query the API using postman. It for some reason sends a ARRAffinity cookie with every request along with the bearer token.

However, when I call the same API endpoint with fiddler without he cookie. It fails with a 401 Randomly. YES Randomly some requests would get 200 success and some would fail with 401.

However, when I pass the ARRAffinity cookie via fidler. It works without any failure.

Is there a way to stop Web Api or azure from generating the ARRAffinity cookie. I just want to use bearer  and not the cookie.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to stop Web Api or azure from generating the ARRAffinity cookie.

We can easily turn ARR Affinity off in the azure portal. detail steps are as blow:

Step 1:  Navigate to your Web Api in the Azure portal.

Step 2:  Select **Application settings** in the **Settings** blade.

Step 3:  Off ARR Affinity.

Step 4:  Select Save.

For more information please refer to [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/05/16/disable-session-affinity-cookie-arr-cookie-for-azure-web-apps/)

[image]

Comment: Is there any way that we can secure ARRAffinity cookie in azure ?